# How to access store value in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to get store value like this:

```
 itemtap : function(list, index, target, record) {

      Ext.getStore("nameStore").load();
      console.dir("TEST->"+record.get('id'));
      console.dir("TEST->"+record.get('address'));

}
```

Here I cannot get id, when itemtap.
and I also try this:

```
  var store= Ext.getStore('nameStore');
  console.dir("TEST->"+store.get('id'));
  console.dir("TEST->"+store.get('address'));
```

But could not get data. Why this?

and **What is the difference between this, two type of store value access?**

I add onclick inside the div, itemtap working fine but in Iphone it is not working? why this? Is there any alternative is present in sencha working both android Iphone and others.How to get value in itemptap, from displayed in div which is display from store.

**Edited:**

```
 itemtap :function(list, index, target, record) {
console.log("Clicked---"+record.get('cat_id'));
}
```

Actually, I am not getting above code.

I am try this, and getting value

```
console.log("Clicked--"+record.data.data[index].cat_id);
```

Getting first value always, because index value always 0, every category tapped.
So, Here I want get index of tapped category.

**Works Fine, If i do this:**

```
{    
          xtype: 'list', 
          itemId: 'catList',
          scrollable: false,

    data: [
    { name: 'A', cat_id: 1},
    { name: 'B', cat_id: 2},
    { name: 'C', cat_id: 3},
    { name: 'D', cat_id: 4},
    { name: 'E', cat_id: 5},


    ],
    loadingText: "Loading Words...",
    emptyText: '<div>{message}</div>',
    autoLoad:true,
    itemTpl:[
    '<tpl for=".">',
          '<span >{name}</span> ',             
      '</tpl>',
    ] 
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you 'reloading' the store on the *itemTap* callback? It should be already loaded and not necessary to load() again.

Even if you want to *update* the store, you should wait for load() to finish before doing record.get(). Remember *load()* is async.

The second block will never work because *get()* is a method for record, you re executing it to the store.

```
itemtap : function(list, index, target, record) {
      console.dir("TEST->" + record.get('id'));
      console.dir("TEST->" + record.get('address'));
}
```

Comment: i try this also,console.log("Clicked--"+record.get('id')); but could not get value.so i try above.

Comment: Why I am not getting exact value from record.get(index)); value.Here every tapping i am getting 0.

Comment: index is the numeric index of the record within the store. You could store.getAt(index) to get an specific record. index=0 means the user taps on the list-item that is saved as the first record of the store. record.get(field) is for reading the value of an specific field of the record.

Comment: Actually, i did this, but could not getting proper value. see my edited question.